# how to read data from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently using Laravel 5.
In my GoalsController:

```
public function getGoalData()
{
    // my queries
    return view('userPages.usercp')->with('goal_data', $goal_data);
}
```

When I print out `$goal_data` by `<?php echo $goal_data ?>`, it's a json string.
Now I want to read it by using Javascript to further process. How can I do that?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I want to read that `@goal_data` in an external script. Here is the solution from `Julian Paolo Dayag` and `VMcreator`.

- In your HTML file, put this at the end (before `</body>` tag):

`<script> window.GOALS = <?echo json_encode($goal_data); ?> </script>`

according to Julian Paolo Dayag:

> by storing a variable into the window object, means it will become a
>   global variable.

- Now in your JS file, you can call it like this: `var goalData = JSON.parse(GOALS);`

Comment: use JSON.parse() in javascript

Comment: I know JSON.parse() but I don't know how to pass a php's variable into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` in javascript to parse JSON string into Object.

```
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
```

read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

**EDIT**

you can do it like this:

```
<script>
     var goal_data=JSON.parse(<?php echo $goal_data ?>);
</script>
```

Well if its in a blade in laravel you can use `JSON.parse({{ $goal_data }});`

**EDIT**

I tried your sample JSON string like this:

```
<?php 
$goal='[
    {
        "goalId":28,
        "title":"1st goal",
        "description":"what the fuck",
        "startTime":"00:00:00",
        "endTime":"22:00:00",
        "remind":0,
        "autocheck":1,
        "repeat":"once",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"daily",
        "freqYear":0,
        "start":"08\/13\/2015",
        "end":""
    },
    {
        "goalId":29,
        "title":"2nd goal",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "startTime":"17:25:00",
        "endTime":"17:25:00",
        "remind":1,
        "autocheck":0,
        "repeat":"once",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"daily",
        "freqYear":0,
        "start":"08\/13\/2015",
        "end":""
    },
    {
        "goalId":30,
        "title":"3rd goal",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "startTime":"05:00:00",
        "endTime":"14:00:00",
        "remind":1,
        "autocheck":1,
        "repeat":"until",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"daily",
        "freqYear":0,
        "start":"08\/13\/2015",
        "end":"08\/19\/2015"
    },
    {
        "goalId":31,
        "title":"4th goal",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "startTime":"00:00:00",
        "endTime":"16:00:00",
        "remind":0,
        "autocheck":1,
        "repeat":"once",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"weekly",
        "freqYear":2015,
        "start":"1",
        "end":""
    },
    {
        "goalId":32,
        "title":"5th goal",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "startTime":"00:00:00",
        "endTime":"00:00:00",
        "remind":1,
        "autocheck":1,
        "repeat":"until",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"weekly",
        "freqYear":2015,
        "start":"9",
        "end":"14"
    },
    {
        "goalId":33,
        "title":"6th goal",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "startTime":"00:00:00",
        "endTime":"00:00:00",
        "remind":1,
        "autocheck":1,
        "repeat":"once",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"monthly",
        "freqYear":2018,
        "start":"8",
        "end":""
    },
    {
        "goalId":34,
        "title":"7th goal",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "startTime":"00:00:00",
        "endTime":"20:00:00",
        "remind":0,
        "autocheck":1,
        "repeat":"until",
        "goalStatus":"success",
        "type":"yearly",
        "freqYear":0,
        "start":"2015",
        "end":"2029"
    }
]';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(JSON.parse(<?php echo  json_encode($goal) ?>));
</script>
```

It works without an error.

**EDIT**

If you want to pass your php variable into external JS, you can assign it to global variable,in your head tag, your code should look like this:

```
..assuming this is your head tag
<script>
    var goal_string=<?php echo json_encode($goal_data); ?>;
</script>
<script src="external_js.js" ></script>
```

Now you can access `var goal_string` on external_js.js and any JS included below its declaration.

Comment: Thank you. But if I use PHP code in `JSON.parse()`, it returned me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. The similar error when using laravel blade: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Make sure your json string is valid.

Comment: did you use json_encode() in php? to convert arrays into json string

Comment: I tried again, wrapped `$goal_data` with `json_encode()` like that `return view('userPages.usercp')->with('goal_data', json_encode($goal_data));`. However, the error stills here

Comment: can you echo $goal_data and post the result?

Comment: JSON.parse({{{ $goal_data }}}); - try to remove the wrapping double qoutes

Comment: My JS file is just to test, so it only has `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: you're using blade template? try to use native php

Comment: yes, I tried `JSON.parse("<?php echo $goal_data ?>");` but it still not works

Comment: without the double qoutes?

Comment: Ive updated my answer, using your JSON string as an example, hope it works for you

Comment: I insert it directly in the html file, it works fine, but how can I call from external JS file ?

Comment: you need to assign a global variable

Comment: Edited my answer- but I think your last request is not connected to your question, please do your research too

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse("json string here");`

example:

Single Object

```
    var person = JSON.parse("{name: 'hello world', age: 18}");

    console.log(person.name); // outputs "hello world"
    console.log(person.age);  // outputs 18
```

Array of Objects

```
    var person = JSON.parse("[{name: 'hello world', age: 18},{name: 'foo bar', age: 10}]");

    console.log(person[0].name); // outputs "hello world"
    console.log(person[0].age);  // outputs 18
    console.log(person[1].name); // outputs "foo bar"
    console.log(person[1].age);  // outputs 10
```

There are times that your **JSON string** is faulty which results the **JSON.parse()** to throw an Exception when parsing fails.

It is recommended to wrap the **JSON.parse()** around a **try/catch block**, so that javascript will not stop the execution of your script.

```
    try {
        var person = JSON.parse("[{name: 'hello world', age: 18},{name: 'foo bar', age: 10}]");

        console.log(person[0].name); // outputs "hello world"
        console.log(person[0].age);  // outputs 18
        console.log(person[1].name); // outputs "foo bar"
        console.log(person[1].age);  // outputs 10
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("JSON parse failure!");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, however, it not works for me. When I tried both of your examples, Chrome returned me the same error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token n`

Comment: when you echo your json string, please make sure that you wrap those in qoutes... like this `JSON.parse("<?php echo addslashes($goal_data); ?>");` and not `JSON.parse(<?php echo $goal_data ?>);`

Comment: I'm sure that I wrapped it with quotes :( even when I copied your examples, it still gives me that error.

Comment: the error is still here `Unexpected token <`. That's weird

Comment: can you please try including the JSON string you are trying to include? so we can check if there is a syntax error?

Comment: By the way, did you use PHP function `json_encode()` before echoing your json string?

Comment: I don't think errors come from my JSON string, because even when I tried with some samples JSON like `[{name: 'hello world', age: 18},{name: 'foo bar', age: 10}]`, it still gives me error

Comment: Are you sure that the error comes from the code block of JSON.parse? I think the error is generated somewhere else... maybe try looking more on your javascript file and check for syntax error

Comment: If you don't mind sharing, is it okay if you also pastebin the whole javascript code? I mean the final output when you view the source of your page

Comment: I think so. Does JSON.parse() require any libraries or something else?

Comment: Nope. It's a built-in javascript API

Comment: my script file don't have other code, just a testing file for me to try JSON.parse()

Comment: Can you pastebin the resulting code in the view-source?

Comment: Do you mean HTML file ?

Comment: Yes, but the final output. I mean what you see when you view the source of the page from the browser

Comment: Here is the final output with the JSON echoed above, please take a look at it: http://pastebin.com/fvzgf08G

Comment: As I looked on the source, it seems that your JSON string wasn't able to reach your JS.

Comment: As you can see, your JSON string was echoed even before the <html> tag. and is even not in a <script> tag

Comment: So, what's your suggestion ?

Comment: My suggestion is to echo the JSON string into the correct location and store it into a javascript variable... http://pastebin.com/SeF8HvKT

by storing a variable into the window object, means it will become a global variable and you can access it on any of your js files

Comment: if it is in js i would use Post or getjson for json and data['name']; for get name of user name from json array :) so i don't need parse json

Comment: Thank you, It works for me. Please post it as an answer so I can verify it.

Answer (score 0):

there are various way to do it Using JS:-

```
var person = JSON.parse("[{JSON1: 'Value1', JSON2: value2},{JSON1: 'Value1', JSON2: Value2}]");
console.log(person[0].JSON1);
console.log(person[0].JSON2);
alert(person[0].JSON1);
alert(person[0].JSON2);
```

Using Java Code :

```
 String s = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
 Object obj = parser.parse(s);
 JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
 System.out.println(array.get(1));
```

or in PHP access file inside Script tag:-

```
 var goal_data=JSON.parse("<?php echo $goal_data ?>");
```

Comment: When I copied your first example, I got the similar error when I tried methods in other comments